# My validation script does not work properly

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
function validate()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ( username==null || username=="" && password==null || password=="");
    {
        alert("Please enter username and password");
        return false;
    }
    else ( username == "james1"  && password == "j1j22j3j" )
    {
       alert ("Login successfully");
       window.location = "http://www.dtrekrun.com/training.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
       return false;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to validate the username/password and show an alert. But it is not working for me.

Comment: `else` should be `else if`

Comment: And remove the semicolon from the end of the `if` line.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you see any error in the console?

Remove the semicolon at the end of this line:

```
if ( username==null || username=="" && password==null || password=="");
```

Else don't take arguments, else if does ! Replace

```
else ( username == "james1"  && password == "j1j22j3j" )
```

by

```
else if ( username == "james1"  && password == "j1j22j3j" )
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
if ( username==null || username=="" && password==null || password=="")
```

instead of

```
if ( username==null || username=="" && password==null || password=="");
```

and

```
else ( username == "james1"  && password == "j1j22j3j" )
```

by

```
else if ( username == "james1"  && password == "j1j22j3j" )
```

Hope you got success

Answer (score 0):

Just remove semicolon after if ( username==null || username=="" && password==null || password=="");